# How to run Gitlab matrix builds on both Windows/Powershell and Linux/bash?

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci

We're moving our CI from Jenkins to Gitlab and I'm trying to setup a pipeline that runs on both Windows and Linux.

Running multiple Python versions on a Linux gitlab runner works ok by defining versions like this:

```
.versions:
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - PYTHON_VERSION: ['3.7', '3.8', '3.9']
        OPERATING_SYSTEM: ['linux', 'windows']
```

then calling them for each stage they are needed

```
build_wheel:
  parallel: !reference [.versions, parallel]
```

I'm trying to add a Windows runner now and have run into the snag that Powershell syntax is different to bash. Most of the Python calls still work, but calling the activate script needs to be different. How do I switch scripts depending on the operating system?

It doesn't seem to be possible to add rules to a script, so I'm trying something like this

```
.activate_linux: &activate_linux
  rules:
    - if: $OPERATING_SYSTEM == 'linux'
  script:
    - source venv/bin/activate

.activate_windows: &activate_windows
  rules:
    - if: $OPERATING_SYSTEM == 'windows'
  script:
    - .\venv\Scripts\activate

.activate: &activate
  - *activate_linux
  - *activate_windows

before_script:
  - python -m venv venv
  - *activate
  - pip install --upgrade pip wheel "setuptools<60"
```

but it gives me the error: "before_script config should be a string or a nested array of strings up to 10 levels deep".

Is it possible to have one .gitlab-ci.yml file that works on both Windows and Linux? Surely someone has worked this out, but I can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily do this in the yaml with that matrix.

Instead, you can do this:

```
.scripts:
  make_venv:
    - python -m venv venv
  activate_linux:
    - !reference [.scripts, make_venv]
    - source ./venv/bin/activate
  activate_windows:
    - !reference [.scripts, make_venv]
    - venv/Scripts/activate.ps1

.job_template:
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - PYTHON_VERSION: ['3.7', '3.8', '3.9']
  script:
    - pip install --upgrade pip wheel "setuptools<60"
    - # ...


build_linux:
  extends: .job_template
  variables:
    OPERATING_SYSTEM: 'linux'
  before_script:
    - !reference [.scripts, activate_linux]

build_windows:
  extends: .job_template
  variables:
    OPERATING_SYSTEM: 'windows'
  before_script:
    - !reference [.scripts, activate_windows]
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it might do the job, but the linter doesn't like it. "This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 3 column 3". Line 7 is underlined though (- source ...) so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @jon_two sorry, you're right. I introduced an error when writing the answer. I think I fixed it.

Comment: Awesome, got it working! I think using extends was the key, along with keeping the version logic outside of the script.